# How to access a chipcard from powershell?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, pcsc

I'd like to send a chipcard command (an APDU) to a chipcard and read the response from the chipcard.

Because there should be no extra install on the windows system, I'd like to do it within windows powershell.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Is there a C DLL, COM or .NET API for this chipcard?  All three mechanisms can be used from within PowerShell.  Perhaps you could show us what the signature of one of these functions looks like.

Comment: Sorry, I have no special driver. The card should be accessed with PCSC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you find a .NET component capable of sending commands to an APDU.  [Here's an example of a for pay component](http://www.vicman.net/getfree/pcsc1.html).  Once you have a .NET component it should be pretty easy to use from PowerShell sans a few known issues like not be able to easily call generic methods and not being able to create classes/implement interfaces in PowerShell script.